# Supabase JOIN by column jsonb[]

Tags: javascript, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

There is a table of products and categories.
In the products table, the category column contains a JSONB array of the format [1,4], where 1 and 4 are category IDs. How to do a JOIN correctly?

This is how I receive the goods.

```
const {data, count, error} = await supabase.from("products").select("*", { count: "exact" }).overlaps("categories", [1]).range(0, 4).order("id", { ascending: false });
```

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": {
      "en": "Product 1",
      "ro": "Product 1",
    },
    "price": 2300,
    "image": "14.jpeg",
    "slug": "product-1",
    "categories": [1,2]
  }
```

Comment: Really this should be a separate relationship table with proper foreign keys. If that is for some reason not possible, or the order of categories is important, it still would be better to use `int[]` (or `bigint[]`) instead of `jsonb` as the type of the `categories` column

Comment: "*I tried to run in a loop*" - please [edit] your question to include the query that you tried